# How can retrieve a data by parameter in Ionic 3 with Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I have a real-time database on Firebase, and I want to retrieve records from this database using parameters.

[image: Here is the screeshot from that]

For example, in the hierarchy you see, I want to get the data using the uID value. How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

https://javebratt.com/firebase-objects-ionic-2-app/

I have tried the heading "Read Firebase Data" in the article on the link I gave, but I do not know how to update the code if it is written for Ionic 2.

Here is the code I wrote,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Post } from '../../models/models/post';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})

export class ProfilePage {

  public posts: Post[];
  public uID: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private storage: Storage) {

    this.storage.get('uID').then((val) => {
      console.log('uID: ' + val);
      this.uID = val;
      console.log('this.uID: ' + this.uID);

      this.db.list<Post>('/Post/',
        ref => ref.orderByChild('uID').equalTo(this.uID)).valueChanges().subscribe(t => {
          this.posts = t;
        })
    });

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProfilePage');
  }

}
```

According to the article I had to do create a variable which is type of "Reference", but with AngularFireDatabase it is not possible to make such a definition.

How do I update this definition in Ionic 3?

**UPDATE**

I added some codes;

```
db.database.ref('/User/').on('value', res => {
      console.log("Try Val: " + res.val)
      console.log("Try Key: " + res.key)
      console.log("Try Child: " + res.child)
    });
```

And outputs;

```
Try Val: function () {
        util_1.validateArgCount('DataSnapshot.val', 0, 0, arguments.length);
        return this.node_.val();
    }
Try Key: User
Try Child: function (childPathString) {
        util_1.validateArgCount('DataSnapshot.child', 0, 1, arguments.length);
        // Ensure the childPath is a string (can be a number)
        childPathString = String(childPathString);
        validation_1.validatePathString('DataSnapshot.child', 1, childPathString, false);
        var childPath = new Path_1.Path(childPathString);
        var childRef = this.ref_.child(childPath);
        return new DataSnapshot(this.node_.getChild(childPath), childRef, PriorityIndex_1.PRIORITY_INDEX);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I could get data, but it's not clear answer.

Firebase records all data with a key value. I also added this key value after the "/ Post /" value as the data path. For example "/ Post / -1ersksnu0nsw1 /".

Here is the code;

```
 db.database.ref('/User/-L88gtymS5pS3KWtZrmI').on('value', res => {
      console.log(res.val().email)
    });
```

And I could get true value, but I still do not know how to do this according to the columns of their records.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina I actually could not try anything, because although it was quite easy to get listed, I could not find any clear information on this topic.

Comment: https://javebratt.com/firebase-objects-ionic-2-app/
https://javebratt.com/firebase-list-ionic-2/

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina thanks for your reply, I tried "Read Firebase data" topic, but it throw syntax error on Ionic 3 with AngularFire. I will update question with that.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina I updated post

Answer (score 1):

EUREKA!

```
db.database.ref('/User/').orderByChild('uID').equalTo(this.uID).once('value', (snapshot) => {
   console.log(snapshot.val().email)
})
```

This code will do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this [tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/5a629d9880aca7059c142976/build-ionic-3-angular-5-and-firebase-simple-chat-app). It create a chat app but it may help you on what you want to to.

```
firebase.database().ref('/Post/').on('value', resp => {
    console.log(resp)
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers, but I could not use "firebase.database().ref...", I injected a AngularFirebaseDatabase variable in my constructor and it has none of those used like yours.